# Structure pointer forward declaration?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list, structure

I am new to c programming and creating linked list data structure, MY teacher gave me some code which seems a bit confusing :

```
typedef struct node *ptr;
ptr start,current;
typedef struct node{
    int value;
    ptr next;
};
```

This code works fine and using the other functions i can create a linked list , my confusion is that, when i change the code like this:

```
node *start;
node *current;
typedef struct node{
    int value;
    node *next;
};
```

it doesn't work .What is wrong with this code why cant i forward declare the  node pointers anymore.

Comment: Please double-check your code. The first example won't work, either.

Comment: One would generally declare the types first, then the variables of that type.

Comment: Also, if you get a compiler or linker error, make sure to include the full text of the error ("doesn't work" is not sufficient).

Comment: Avoid typedefs when learning C. Their only purpose is to confuse novice users.

Comment: first one is working fine. what error did you find in that ?

Comment: @wildplasser That's incorrect. Typedef's are an integral part of the C language and important for even a novice to understand.

Comment: @ConnorHollis They are *very confusing* to novice users, and in most cases not needed. And they can be taught later, after the basics have been covered.

Comment: @wildplasser Is a struct not considered basic? It's a foundation of the C language. I would argue that it's a feature that needs to be covered early on and not later.

Comment: A struct is basic, but you do not *need* the typedef.

Comment: Please tell your teach that `typedef`ing a pointer is very confusing, as it hide the pointer sematics. It should not be done for normal usage and shall not for beginner's code. In general, it is better just to `typedef` the `struct` and require explicit pointer syntax to use a pointer.

Comment: @wildplasser: The problem is `typedef`ing a pointer, not the `typedef` as such. It would be fine to `typedef` the latter.

Comment: @wildplasser I don't think it wise to teach someone a method and then change the information on them later. If you are teaching structures then it makes sense for someone to learn both the keyword struct variable declaration and the struct typedef method.

Comment: @ConnorHollis `typedef` has nothing to do with `struct`, it's just often used to hide the fact your type is a `struct`.

Comment: @ConnorHollis: `typedef` has nothing to do with `struct`. However, it is generally a good idea to introduce `typedef` before `struct`s, etc. and when it comes to `struct`s use it naturally.

Comment: @Olaf: that is correct, but typedeffing the node *and* the pointer will end up in having three ways to represent the same thing, when only one is needed. Is only adds a lot of visual(and mental) fluff.

Comment: @wildplasser: Please read my comment again. I'm **strictly** against `typedef`ing a pointer. But a `struct` should be `typedef`ed along with its definition and the `struct mystruct` syntax should only be used where required (i.e. as forward reference).

Comment: I don't mean to imply that a typedef is only useful for a struct. But I believe typedef is a powerful tool that people argue is "too challenging." In my opinion it is a basic feature of the language that shoud be taught early. I don't agree that typedef'ing a pointer is always right but it can be useful.

Comment: Also this is a hell of a comment thread on this question. I don't have anything else to say about this but if others do maybe the conversation should move to some kind of chat?

Comment: @olaf: I read it. I am **even** against using a typedef for the node, since it is not needed. (its only purpose is to avoid typeing the `struct` keyword) BTW: I think we agree. It can come in handy for introducing *opaque* types.

Comment: @ConnorHollis: "... but it can be useful." Only for opaque handles and they it should be better made a `uintptr_t` or at least `void *`.

Comment: @wildplasser: About the pointer we might agree, but not about `typedef`ing a `struct`. My standard policy is to always `typedef` them along with the declaration (I'm against seperating `typedef` and declaration, however. That ´struct` tag syntax is a C-special anyway; most other languages don't even support such (although it comes handy for recursive pointers, of course).

Comment: @ConnorHollis in your typical coding guidelines, you will find qualifiers like "consider", "avoid" and "always"/"never". Typedef'ing a pointer IMHO belongs into the "avoid" category. You *can* do it, but if you choose to, have a good reason and document it. The teacher's code *here* would definitely fail my code review ....

Comment: @Olaf: there could be a place for that, sometimes, somewhere. But it certainly is confusing for novice users. (WRT pointer-typedeffing: take a look at libxml2; it can even confuse experienced users ;-)

Comment: @wildplasser I agree with Olaf, and also a *bit* with you. When thinking "in objects", the separate struct namespace of C is a legacy that doesn't have any expressive value. On the other hand, when you use a `struct` very traditionally as an "all public" data container, it could make sense to explicitly refer to it as a `struct` on any usage.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Even when entering the definition into the "typedef namespace", the "struct namespace" still exists, as a parallel universe.

Comment: @wildplasser there's no "typedef namespace" as it uses the global namespace like builtin types ... and concerning the "struct namespace" -- yes, it's always there, but that doesn't mean you *have* to use it. Code for clarity, make intentions clear, and make underlying technical concepts explicit *exactly* where this information is valuable to the consumer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
typedef struct node *ptr;
ptr start,current;
typedef struct node{
    int value;
    ptr next;
};
```

The typedef for the struct itself won't work this way, I guess you're missing a `node` at the end (It's missing the identifier of the newly defined type).

At this point, I'd tell your teacher to please **not** confuse everyone by `typedef`ing a pointer type. It's widely common to have the pointer type modifier visible on every usage, just to make it obvious it *is* a pointer. But now to the actual answer:

```
node *start;
node *current;
typedef struct node{
    int value;
    node *next;
};
```

Start at the first line: you use `node` here as a type identifier. But you didn't tell the compiler yet what kind of type `node` should be. In fact, what you're actually missing *is* a forward declaration. It would work like the following:

```
/* forward-declare "struct node" and at the same time define the type
 * "node" to be a "struct node":
 */
typedef struct node node;

/* now use your type by declaring variables of that type: */
node *start;
node *current;

/* finally fully declare your "struct node": */
struct node {
    int value;
    node *next;
};
```

Or, without the `typedef`, that easily confuses a beginner:

```
struct node; /* forward declaration (not strictly necessary in this little example) */

struct node *start;
struct node *current;

struct node {
    int value;
    struct node *next;
};
```

Comment: I don't agree that typedef'ing a pointer type for a struct is a bad practice. I think a well named pointer typedef can be clarifying and useful in certain instances. Great answer though.

Comment: @ConnorHollis there are differing opinions on that matter, still you find it banned a lot. Rationale is everyone knows that the asterisk in a declaration modifies the type to be a pointer. At best, you would replace that by some pre- or postfix "ptr", "p_" or whatever. It doesn't help clarity but instead makes you look twice when understanding other people's code.

Comment: @ConnorHollis the only valid reason to do it anyways I can think of right now is some kind of "opaque handle" where calling code should know *nothing* about it and just pass it to the respective API as-is. -- surely doesn't really apply in this typical "linked list" scenario.

Comment: In fact, you do not even need the incomplete type. The resulting code will become shorter, too.

Comment: @wildplasser sure you do, as soon as you need the `next` member

Comment: @wildplasser just realized you're talking about the "typedef-free" version. Then, yes, indeed. I'll leave the forward declaration there anyways as it helps to see what the actual forward declaration is (as opposed to the typedef)

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing in the second case is not a forward declaration.  It's attempting to use a type (`node`) without defining it.

The first case doesn't quite work either.  It gives the following warning:

> warning: useless storage class specifier in empty declaration

That is because you're not assigning a type alias for `struct node`.  You'd have to do it like this:

```
typedef struct node{
    int value;
    ptr next;
} node;
```

Now, you can use `node` in place of `struct node`.